# Subsemigroup of a finite semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

Let $S$ be a finite semigroup and $T \subseteq S$ which satisfy the following property:

- For $x, y \in T$, we have $x, y \in \langle z \rangle$ for some $z \in S$.
- If $H \subseteq S$ satisfy the above property and $T \subseteq H$, then  $H = T$.

> > Is $T$ forms a subsemigroup of $S$.

I have tried to find out the counter example of a semigroup $S$ and a subset $T$ of $S$ which satisfies these two properties but it does not form a subsemigroup of $S$. But I am unable to find this. After that, I have tried to prove $T$ forms a subsemigroup. It is sufficient to prove for any $a, b, c \in T$, there exist $d \in S$ such that $ab, c \in  \langle d \rangle.$ From the given hhypothesis, there exist $x, y, z \in S$ such that $a,b \in \langle x \rangle$,  $a, c  \in \langle y \rangle$, $b,c \in \langle z \rangle$. I am stuck here. Thanks for your any kind of help.

Comment: What does $\langle z \rangle$ mean?

Comment: For $ z \in S$, $\langle z  \rangle = \{ z^n \; : \; n \in \mathbb N\}$

Comment: You haven't used the second property. I don't know the full answer yet, but it's not hard to prove that $T$ is at least closed under powers: if $x\in T$, then $\langle x\rangle\subseteq T$. To verify this, take $H=T\cup\langle x\rangle$ and verify it satisfies the given property and contains $T$, from which you deduce $H=T$.

Comment: I have verified that for any $x \in T$, we have $\langle x \rangle \subseteq T$ so that $H = T = T \cup \langle x \rangle$. From this, how we conclude that $T$ satisfy the closure property.

Comment: @user120386: As I indicated, “I don’t know the full answer yet.” I just pointed out that you hadn’t used the second property (from which this one follows), or the finiteness, for that matter. I’ve been thinking about it bit on and off, but haven’t quite gotten it; I did not mean to imply that this property by itself would solve the problem.  But it is an example of using the second property of $T$.

Comment: A lot of thanks for giving me your valuable time.